Ubuntu installed with very small desktop window
First, I bought a laptop from eBay that had windows that was supposed to function properly. Upon powering on the display showed windows but said to activate windows. Second, I took it to Best Buy for them to wipe the hard drive and install Ubuntu. It didn't work. I took it home and finally got the machine to boot but the screen was so small I couldn't see it hardly, let alone see the menu tabs at the top.
I'm thinking it's a screen resolution thing but am a newby and don't know how to fix. Also, the battery died and I just bought a replacement to put in the weekend and will see if I can find out how to open a terminal window and try some command line fixes.
Oh, and I forgot to mention that I did hook up a small tv as a second monitor that's much larger than the laptop screen and found out to enlarge to the desktop somewhat. I still cannot hardly ready the menu up at the top of the desktop.
Also, I thought that if there is only one OS (Ubuntu) installed that the desktop would take up the entire screen.  Mayby I'm wrong.
I truly hope that someone can answer my questions so I can get this laptop up and running.
Thanks in advance!!

On my ancient laptop there is 1366x768 resolution. Xubuntu 24.04 works.

If you go to Setting, Display, first enable Fractional scaling and confirm,
Then you can increase the size of window, be careful do not increase it too much or you will not be able to use your laptop scrren, then if that did not work in resoultion change it to one lower see if this helps, there is also Accessibility which does not always show, you write in Acceptability in Setting and in the seeing you can enable Large text and larger cursor.
This is for Ubuntu 24.04 if you have another version, things might be different. Just tell us which version.

What is the screen resolution you see in display settings?

Can you post a screenshot?
